What is the proper exception to raise when two objects are not allowed to have duplicate instance variables? Should I create my own?
Say I have a class "Bank" whose instances hold Customer objects in dictionaries keyed by their customer_id (or something like that).
Customer in turn has attributes "Name" and "personalId/ Social Security number/ stateId"
Two customers have to be able to share the same name (happens sometime in real life if you have a common first and last name), but they should not be able to have the same personalIdNbr since that implies we have registered the same customer multiple times as different people.
def newCustomer(bank_: Bank) -> None:
    try:
        name = input("Name: ")
        personIdNbr = input("Social security number: ")
        customerId = bank_.add_customer(name, personIdNbr) #raise here?
        print(f"Customer added with customerid: {customerId}")
    except MyException:
        print(f"Customer with social security {personIdNbr} allready in system")
    except KeyboardInterupt:
        print("No new customer added.")
    finally
        input() # Give them a chance to read whats printed before the program continues

Would it be "pythonic" to create my own exception for this use case? What should I name it then?
So far add_customer() simply returns 'None' when the social security is already registered (thats simply part of the spec), and I have an if block to check if this is the case, but it doesn't seem like a very "pythonic" way to do things, (more LYBL than EAFP).

Aint the pythonic way to use sth that already exists and not create sth new?

If you are using a database for a bank, that could be called IntegrityError or ConstraintError.

A custom exception seems perfectly reasonable. Call it whatever you like

As an aside, the first two calls to input should probably go before the try statement, and it's probably not the job of this function to prevent Ctrl-C from exiting the program.

What other ways are there for the user to quit a submenu if i want to keep things simple and only use the built in input() function and not something more elaborate? @chepner

"Name (Type 'q' to quit):" and check right after inputting name if q has been entered. Of course that means you can't name customer q, but I doubt that's an issue.

@Minimo Good point; it's not that big an issue for the user to type Ctrl-C again if necessary.

A subclass of ValueError like DuplicateAccountException, if not simply a ValueError itself, would be appropriate.
